# How to patchValue values from FormArray?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I need to patch the value from formArray
I first get all values

```
const control = this.addressPoiForm.get("tableRows") as FormArray;
```

Second find item which i want to edit(patch)

```
const item = control.value.filter((valueForm:any) => valueForm.placeId === pin.oldValue.pointId);
```

item when console.log(item[0]) i got

```
isEditable: false
latitude: 40.67028015
longitude: -73.85288055
name: "galop"
placeId: 283
```

I need this item to change.
When i try:

```
item[0].patchValue({
  isEditable: false,
  latitude: pin.drag?.coords.lat,
  longitude: pin.drag?.coords.lng,
  name: pin.oldValue.name,
  placeId: pin.oldValue.pointId,
})
```

I got error:

> core.js:5980 ERROR TypeError: item[0].patchValue is not a function

I am also try with setValue no work...
Help how to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.value` gives you the raw values of the controls in the array. So when you do

```js
const item = control.value.filter((valueForm:any) => valueForm.placeId === pin.oldValue.pointId);
```

you are actually setting `item` to an array of the values, not the FormControls. However, `.patchValue` is a property of a FormControl. You can get the matching control/controls you want by using the `.controls` property ([documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray#controls)). It would look something like the following (I renamed some variables to make it more clear):

```js
const arr = this.addressPoiForm.get("tableRows") as FormArray;
const matchingControls = arr.controls.filter((control: FormControl) => control.value.placeId === pin.oldValue.pointId);
matchingControls[0].patchValue({...});
```

Comment: I am using form Builder for this.. will this work if i use formBuilder? Yes this is work, can you explain me better how this exactly work and i will vote up

Comment: Yes it should still work. The types of all the controls are all the same. FormBuilder just gives you some convenience methods to create the fom.

Comment: You were getting "item[0].patchValue is not a function" because patchValue is a property of the angular FormControl type. When you did .value.filter, instead of .controls.filter, you were getting back an array of your plain javascript objects (with properties isEditable, latitude, etc...) instead of an array of FormControls. .value gives you the value that's actually entered into the FormControls, vs the FormControl objects  themselves